# WebRTC P2P between Browser and Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io, webrtc

I am trying to initiate a rtc connection between a browser and a nodejs server.

For the signaling part i am using socket io. On the server side for rtc i am using `rtc-everywhere` (also tried with `wrtc`).

I got the exchanges of offers and ice candidates working but event `onaddstream` on server side doesn't seem to fire.

I am wondering if i am doing this correctly and even if this is possible at all.

My end goal is to record the rtc stream on server side.

I put all my code into a repo: https://gitlab.com/tere/rtc-test.

In `public/js/main.js` is the browser code and in `app.js` is the server code.

Tried with latest version of Chrome + node v9.2.1.

For the iceServers i tried with google public server and also a local one (used https://github.com/enobufs/stun)

Any support will be much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: The library says "MediaStream APIs are not supported at this time"

Comment: @KeyneViana yeap, missed that. Left the question open just to see if anyone manages to do this somehow

Comment: You may look for webrtc native. There's a nodejs library which uses it https://github.com/vmolsa/webrtc-native

Comment: @AndreiTerecoasa sal